# getting image from a picturebox

Tags: vb.net

how can i get an image that i drawn on a picturebox? in my application i created a form with the freehand drawing.but i can't save the image that i drawn as a file,there have a error message that "object reference not set to an instance of an object".I am using the code

```
me.picturebox1.image.save(filename,sysytem.....jpeg)
```

any one knows please help me...thank you

Answer (score 4):

I will assume that you never assign the `Image` property of your `PictureBox` but instead perform drawing commands directly on a `Graphics` object retrieved from the PictureBox control. If that is the case, the `Image` property will remain `Nothing`/`null` when you perform the drawing. To get around this, assign an empty image to the `Image` property when you initialize the `PictureBox` control:

```
myPictureBox.Image =  New Bitmap(myPictureBox.ClientSize.Width, _
                                 myPictureBox.ClientSize.Height)
```

Then, when you want to perform some drawing, use a `Graphics` object from the `Image` instead of the `PictureBox`:

```
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myPictureBox.Image)
    ' do the drawing '
End Using
```

With this approach you can save the image as you do in your current code, by simply calling `Save` on the `PictureBox.Image` object.

Comment: thanks for your answer.but please tell me where can i place this code

Comment: @sinoydevassy: that really depends on the structure of your application, but if you have a point of the code where you initialize a "new drawing", that would be the place for assigning the new, empty `Bitmap` object.

Comment: thank u so much.it's working good.i initialize in the form load.thank you.but there have a problem.the saved image's background color is everytime black.so i cant see my image because my drawing pen color is also black.thank you

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be nothing intrinsically wrong with your code (unless the problem is with one of the parameters). `PictureBox.Image.Save()` does work!

It is possible that the PictureBox displays an image, but the `Image` object referenced by it is already disposed. You can get rid of the Object reference error by implementing a check for nullability first :

```
If picturebox1.Image isnot Nothing Then
  ...
End If
```

In addition, you should check the code that draws the Image... does it dispose of references as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar operation.

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\\tempStack.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

The cause could be that the pictureBox1 (very unlikely) or pictureBox1.Image is not set.

Use

```
pictureBox1.Load("")
```

to load the image before trying to save it.

Comment: Not set meaning Nothing or Null reference.