# picturebox image

Tags: vb.net

```
myPictureBox.Image =  New Bitmap(myPictureBox.ClientSize.Width, _
                                 myPictureBox.ClientSize.Height)
```

and

```
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myPictureBox.Image)
    ' do the drawing '
End Using
```

thanks for your answer. But please tell me where can i place this code.

Comment: Include this as an edit to your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398069/getting-image-from-a-picturebox

Answer (score 0):

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Bmp Files(*.bmp)|*.bmp|Gif Files(*.gif)|*.gif|Jpg Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg"
            OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            txtEmpPicture.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            PicText.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```