# Fit image in picturebox without saving image beforehand?

Tags: vb.net, save, jpeg, scale, picturebox

I have a picture box. The user can draw different `rectangles` on it, assuming that the user draws `rectangles` which go beyond the size of the `picturebox`, can I uniformly resize the contents to fit the `picturebox`, even though the image is not saved yet?.

I can only manage to `resize` content that has been loaded in from and already saved image file. The code that I am using to draw `rectangles` is as follows:

```
gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 2, 75)
```

`Rectangles` do appear on `picturebox` as would be expected. 
Also I am unable to save using the following code:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\test\myimage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

The error that I get is:
    `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Please, post more relevant code to determine the source of the error (I guess that the PictureBox1.Image.Save is written when PictureBox1 does not have any image). Also please elaborate more on "user draws rectangles which go beyond the size of the picturebox" -> how is the user expected to draw the rectangles?

Comment: Use a container, like panel?

Answer (score 1):

I use `System.IO.MemoryStream` when I want to fill pictureboxes with images without saving to the hard drive.

```
PictureBox1.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Banksy.on.the.thekla.arp.jpg")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your PictureBox has no "Image" object assigned to it.

You can find the solution here (first answer): [getting image from a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398069/getting-image-from-a-picturebox)

[Also, you might face issues later on with regards to saving to your root folder (C:). Try to use a folder on your local Desktop, for example, to avoid any access-permission errors.]

**Edit:** 
This is taken from the above link. It appears to me that you have not tried it.

```
myPictureBox.Image =  New Bitmap(myPictureBox.ClientSize.Width, _
                                 myPictureBox.ClientSize.Height) 

'Then, when you want to perform some drawing, use a Graphics object from the Image instead of the PictureBox:

Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(myPictureBox.Image)
    ' do the drawing ' 
End Using
```

Comment: which I dont get cause I thougth the same thing however the image clearly is in the picture box cause when I move it on the form the image still only displays in the picturebox `Dim gr As Graphics gr = Me.PictureBox1.CreateGraphics gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 2, 75) PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\test\myimage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)` the C:\ root folder is cause im still only testing though this will be done with a save dialogue box latter on

Comment: The drawing you are making is ON the 'PictureBox', but is not part of the 'Image' property. Your Image property is not set, and that's why you are getting that error.

Have you looked at the link I sent you?

This is what you have to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398069/getting-image-from-a-picturebox/1398222#1398222

Follow that code, and it should work.

Regardless of whether you are testing or not, your efforts to save the file in root C: can fail due to access restrictions, and more often than not, there will be no error to help you identify the issue.