# VB.net - printing picture box

Tags: vb.net, printing, picturebox

So I have made a drawing in a picture box. I draw in a BMP then load the BMP in the picturebox using this code:

```
   PcbNetwerk.BackgroundImage = bmpNO
```

Then I try to print using the following code:

```
Dim WithEvents PrintDoc As New PrintDocument()

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(PcbNetwerk.Image, 0, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub BtnPrintNetwerk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrintNetwerk.Click

    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If

End Sub
```

but it only results in blank prints. Also when I select a paper printer I only end up with a empty PDF file. I have been searching for a solution for hours now but everything I finds leads back to the same sort of code and I get the same results (blank pages and in some cases my program even crashes). The size I want to print to is A3 landscape format.

Comment: I don't know anything about rendering bitmaps, so my suggestion is to try other file types. Get something, anything, in there first, then try to figure out why your picture isn't being shown. Can you get it to print text, for instance?

Comment: when I want to print text I should replace the  e.Graphics.DrawImage(PcbNetwerk.Image, 0, 0) in PrintDocument1 but what do I use to set a string there? for example "test printing this page"

Comment: I don't know, you could google around or check other questions here for that. Have you tried debugging? Put a breakpoint on your draw statement, examine/watch the value of PcbNetwerk.Image, etc. Then you can return with information about what the nature of the problem might be - perhaps your image isn't being loaded properly.

Comment: Just found out that PcbNetwerk.image doesnt contain anything. so now I need to figure out how to export the contents of my picture box to img as new bitmap or img as image or something

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398069/2953322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so picturebox1.image resulted in an empy file. to fix this problem I created:

`Public Netwerkoverzicht As Image`

in the public class of my form.

Then I saved the bmp file I generate in one of my subs to this image public I made and use the following code where I replace PcbNetwerk.image with Netwerkwerkoverzicht

```
Dim WithEvents PrintDoc As New PrintDocument() 

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage

e.Graphics.DrawImage(Netwerkoverzicht, 0, 0)

End Sub
```